# I can not be accessing to files of 'domains' directory in openserver with ngrok for setting webhook for telegram bot in windows

Tags: php, windows, ngrok, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Before using windows I was Ubuntu User. When I used ngrok on ubuntu, It automatically accesses to /var/www/html directory, afetr this I can easily open php file which telegram bot codes to see result.

Now on Windows, I am using openserver. Openserever domains directory for php files like /var/www/html in ubuntu.

I installed ngrok.exe. when I type `ngrok.exe http 80` on cmd. I am gettin gall thins correctly:

`Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040`
`Forwarding                    http://5756c0888da3.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80`
`Forwarding                    https://5756c0888da3.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:80`

But when with it I can not be accessing to domains.

I tried this command also:`ngrok.exe http halalBot.test:80` to connect my project directly.

`Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040`
`Forwarding                    http://40b6091d262f.ngrok.io -> http://halalBot.test:80`
`Forwarding                    https://40b6091d262f.ngrok.io -> http://halalBot.test:80`

However, when I tried to see url `http://40b6091d262f.ngrok.io` on browser, this url is not for `http://halalBot.test:80`, namely this project is not being opened on browser, but opening localhost page which is not localhost page of openserver.

Please if someone know how to access to 'domains' directory with ngrok for setting webhook for Telegram bot!

Comment: In case it's helpful you can actually use [ngrok's built-in fileserver](https://ngrok.com/docs#http-file-urls) which might be simpler: `ngrok http file:///<path>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to specify the --host-header parameter so that the server receives the Host header for the correct processing of the request:
`ngrok http --host-header=halalBot.test 80`